# Emptying cache of peaks.js - memory management

Tags: audiocontext, peaks.js

The examples provided with peaks.js are fine when working within a multi-page environment. But not in a single page app environment such as Angular. The provided destroy method only removes the instance of the player but NOT the memory already taken up. How can I clear the cache?

I've tried:

```
peaks.destroy();
```

and

```
audioContext = null;
```

But both haven't worked.

Comment: I am new to Peaks.js and will probably face the same problem you have (had?) soon, too (implementation with Vue). Did you solve the problem in the meantime? – At the moment I have no idea that I could contribute. I was wondering if setting the waveformdata option to empty would help? 
https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js/#configuration

Comment: @RobertWildling in the end I couldn't work it out and nobody could help me. So I went with wavesurfer in the end which deals with memory and SPAs a lot easier

Comment: Can you show a bit more context? Since Javascript engines typically have their own memory management, just destroying objects does not necessarily declare free memory immediately.

Comment: Also, just a thought, might the problem be object URL's that are not properly revoked with  revokeObjectURL() ?

Comment: @RobertWildling Did you get any solution or conclusion to your anticipated memory issues?

Comment: @Marcel The Peaks project has changed a lot since the first post. And my project is done since over a year. I have no memory of this problem anymore. Sorry for not being more helpful here. (But the project still works fine, so I assume cache is no problem anymore; but 48Hz was for timing issues...)